# How to get host element reference?

Tags: typescript, angular

How can I get the host element reference in Angular 2?

In my case, I want to know if my component has a focus or not.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You get the host element reference using

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {
    console.log(this.elRef.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

You can also subscribe to the `focus` event

```
class MyComponent {
  @HostBinding() tabindex = 0;
  @HostListener('focus', ['$event'])
  onFocus(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well this is correct answer, but be aware that ElementRef will only work when angular is running in Browser-Thread - where you have direct access to the DOM - and therefore break when you try to run your app in a webworker... Renderer2 is mentioned in the Docs - to being save to use in this cases - but it's marked as experimental and i couldn't find good docs on how to use it yet. Maybe this saves someone the trouble i just had :)

Comment: Using `ElementRef` is not the problem. The problem is using its `nativeElement` property. The Angular team had a strong opinion against using `ElementRef.nativeElement` in pre-release times, but softened their stance after release because so many were just not interested in WebWorker and Server-Side-Rendering. The main limitation of Renderer2 is that it only allows to set properties of an element, but no way to read from it (otherwise it wouldn't work with SSR and WW).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - any suggestions or links to a Renderer2 Example? My problem is i wanted to 'climb-up' a tree of nested components from a selected one, compare the components constructor-type and set an active-state variable on the intresting ones... i would have liked to do it in a way like with native-element , but know the application will later need the performance gainded from running in a webworker ( also Server-Side-Rendering )... Is my best option to emit an event up the chain, check the parent and store the data in shared-service?

Comment: There is not much to it. You inject it and then call one of its methods and pass an `ElementRef` the method should be applied to https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/ All supported methods are listed in https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Answer (score 5):

Use [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) that represents a container where one or more views can be attached to a component.

```
constructor(private readonly viewRef: ViewContainerRef) {

    console.log(this.viewRef.element.nativeElement);
}
```